# Adding attribute to existing XMLNodes in C#

Tags: asp.net

I am using xml and i have to add new tag in xml.
below XML is :

```
<LoginDetails>
  <Login>
    <FirstName>Abhishek</FirstName>
    <LastName>Pathak</LastName>
    <securityQuestion>What is you DOB</securityQuestion>
    <SecAnswer>31/03/1985</SecAnswer>
    <LoginId>abc</LoginId>
    <Password>1234</Password>
  </Login>

</LoginDetails>
```

and I want to add new tag like:

```
 <Login>
    <FirstName>vivek</FirstName>
    <LastName>sharma</LastName>
    <securityQuestion>What is you DOB</securityQuestion>
    <SecAnswer>27/03/1985</SecAnswer>
    <LoginId>abcd</LoginId>
    <Password>3214</Password>
  </Login>
```

Could any1 give me code in C# for that.

Comment: I don't think this site was built for people to request code snippets...

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to add a node to Login details. Here are some links that will help you.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode.appendchild.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387083.aspx

Comment: hey can you provide me code in C#. as i have shown in my example

Answer (score 0):

So finally i was able to do it myselft:

```
    XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
    xmlDoc.Load(@"D:\abhishek\LoginDetails1.xml");

    XmlElement elmRoot = xmlDoc.DocumentElement;
    XmlElement elmNew = xmlDoc.CreateElement("Login");
    elmRoot.AppendChild(elmNew);


    elmRoot = xmlDoc.DocumentElement;
    elmNew = xmlDoc.CreateElement("FirstName");
    XmlText txtVideo = xmlDoc.CreateTextNode(txtFname.Text);
    elmRoot.LastChild.AppendChild(elmNew);
    elmRoot.LastChild.LastChild.AppendChild(txtVideo);

    elmRoot = xmlDoc.DocumentElement;
    elmNew = xmlDoc.CreateElement("LastName");
    txtVideo = xmlDoc.CreateTextNode(txtLastName.Text);
    elmRoot.LastChild.AppendChild(elmNew);
    elmRoot.LastChild.LastChild.AppendChild(txtVideo);

    elmRoot = xmlDoc.DocumentElement;
    elmNew = xmlDoc.CreateElement("securityQuestion");
    txtVideo = xmlDoc.CreateTextNode(comboBox.SelectedValue.ToString());
    elmRoot.LastChild.AppendChild(elmNew);
    elmRoot.LastChild.LastChild.AppendChild(txtVideo);

    elmRoot = xmlDoc.DocumentElement;
    elmNew = xmlDoc.CreateElement("SecAnswer");
    txtVideo = xmlDoc.CreateTextNode(txtAnswer.Text);
    elmRoot.LastChild.AppendChild(elmNew);
    elmRoot.LastChild.LastChild.AppendChild(txtVideo);
    elmRoot = xmlDoc.DocumentElement;
    elmNew = xmlDoc.CreateElement("LoginId");
    txtVideo = xmlDoc.CreateTextNode(txtLoginId.Text);
    elmRoot.LastChild.AppendChild(elmNew);
    elmRoot.LastChild.LastChild.AppendChild(txtVideo);

    elmRoot = xmlDoc.DocumentElement;
    elmNew = xmlDoc.CreateElement("Password");
    txtVideo = xmlDoc.CreateTextNode(txtPwd.Text);
    elmRoot.LastChild.AppendChild(elmNew);
    elmRoot.LastChild.LastChild.AppendChild(txtVideo);

    xmlDoc.Save(@"D:\abhishek\LoginDetails.xml");
```